# Unsure why 'userApp' module is unavailable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just getting started with angularJS and I'm unsure as to why I'm getting module unavailable.

The first code snippet is the one referenced in the HTML (main.js).

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('userApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = [];
    $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/collector/50001366562').success(function(data) {
      $scope.user = data;
    })
  })
```

```html
<html ng-app="userApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
{{user}}

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please explain why this doesn't work?

In the chrome JS console I get the following errors:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'userApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
>
> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module userApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'userApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `angular.module` can be used both as getter and setter:

You have to use setter when creating new module

```
angular.module('userApp', []);
```

The second param here is dependencies array

When you wanna access your existing module, e. g. to add services, controllers etc you can use getter (w/o second param)

```
angular.module('userApp')
```

Getter will return you the module, it can be called many times during app lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also pretty new to Angular but when you declare a module don't you need that second parameter?

```
angular.module('userApp', []);
```

This solution is what the error message is communicating:

> If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: yes, certainly do, otherwise it is a reference to existing (previously declared) module of that name

Comment: it is possible to assign controllers w/o using global var, but your first statement is truthful

Comment: @ArtemPetrosian yes, you use what you have in question ... with no dependency argument ...`angular.module('userApp').controller('AnotherCtrl'...`

Comment: @ArtemPetrosian ja I know that (I've edited) but not assigning to a variable does mean that the app is then inaccessible (although why you would need access to it, I do not know).

Comment: `it's at least recommended` ... no, is actually best practice now in most style guides to avoid variable. Code is more portable and readable without it

Comment: @charlietfl thats what I'm trying to explain

Comment: Fair enough, I'm curious as to why I see it *all* the time then but I've edited my answer and will look it up...

Comment: Was common convention previously yes. Now more common convention is to use angular.module reference